# How Can I Fix VSCode Import Path Suggestions In Lerna Monorepo?

Tags: javascript, import, visual-studio-code, lerna, monorepo

VSCode does a great job with autosuggesting imports, however inside a (Lerna) monorepo it only suggests relative paths from one package to another, for example:

```
import example from '../../../@scope/example/lib/index.html'
```

I need to refer to other packages using their package names:

```
import example from '@scope/example';
```

My `jsconfig.json` which is at the root of my monorepo:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "jsx": "react"
  },
  "include": ["**/src/**/*.js"],
  "exclude": [
    "**/node_modules/*",
    "**/dist/*",
    "**/coverage/*",
    "**/demo/*",
    "**/lib/*",
    "**/public/*"
  ]
}
```

**Is there any way to get the correct autocompletion in VSCode?**

Note: There is a [plugin](https://github.com/Que3216/vscode-mono-repo-import-fixer/blob/master/src/extension.ts) available, but it only works with `.ts` files.

Comment: Have you tried configuring anything so far, such as creating a tsconfig or jsconfig for example?

Comment: @MattBierner I've added my `jsconfig.json` file to the question.

Answer (score 5):

You can configure `paths` in a [`jsconfig.json`](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/jsconfig) to let VS Code's tooling know how to resolve `@/` paths.

In your `jsconfig.json`, add:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
       "@scope/example/*": [ "./path/to/scope/example/*" ]
    }
  },
   "exclude": [
     "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

You can configure paths to map from any path prefix to a subdirectory in your workspace. See the [path mapping documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html#path-mapping) for more details

Note that paths only effects imports of javascript or typescript files; an `.html` import still won't work properly